# Wait for COM Event to complete

Tags: c#, .net, events, com, message-pump

How do I block the UI thread while waiting for COM event to complete. I subscribe to update event of COM which signals the event has completed.

```
MyRData.OnUpdate += OnUpdate;
```

I do not own the COM code and cannot make changes to it.

I tried AutoResetEvent however that blocks the UI thread and i dont recieve updates from COM.

Comment: How do you know that the COM event is complete?

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen Updated the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up using
    Application.DoEvents()

Comment: You may want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19555959/1768303), specifically `WaitWithDoEvents` from there.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is very similar to @EricBrown's one, but there is one different point.

Creating a [nested message loop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickkramer/archive/2006/05/06/591252.aspx) with `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` may lead to code reentrancy on the same thread (via a window message dispatched by the inner `PeekMessage/TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage` pattern). At worst scenario, you may end up calling the same COM object method *before* the previous call has returned.

I would first try using [CoWaitForMultipleHandles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [COWAIT_DISPATCH_CALLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (but without `COWAIT_DISPATCH_WINDOW_MESSAGES`). In case your COM object is provided by an out-of-proc server, this most likely should work. Otherwise, you should consider putting some reentrancy checks in place.

I have a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050438/handling-ckeditor-async-calls-synchronously-with-c-sharp-winforms-webbrowser-con) with some code showing how it could be done with C# (I had to use `COWAIT_DISPATCH_WINDOW_MESSAGES` there, otherwise the event I was after wasn't getting fired).

**[UPDATE]** Ideally, you should use `async/await` pattern for things like that and wrap your event as a task (e.g. [here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18317508/1768303)). I understand, sometimes it is not feasible to re-factor existing code to use this approach. However, if a pending operation takes considerable time to complete, a more user-friendly way to wait for its completion event might be just to show a modal dialog with a nice "please wait..." message (as discussed  here in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18317508/1768303)). You'd just close this dialog from your event handler. In fact, AFAIK, this is the only endorsed way for a WinForms app to enter a nested message loop.

**[UPDATE]** As Eric pointed out in comments, `COWAIT_DISPATCH_WINDOW_MESSAGES` is indeeded required for an STA thread. Apparently, `COWAIT_DISPATCH_CALLS` is intended for the new little-known [ASTA model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh750290.aspx) and *[has no meaning in other apartment types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*.

In case with out-of-proc COM servers, .NET event handlers are called back as free-threaded objects regardless of the waiting thread's apartment model ([in my experience](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18458398/1768303), it's never the same STA thread on which the out-of-proc object was originally created). Thus, waiting with [WaitHandle.WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx) (no pumping) should be sufficient. However, if the event handler accesses any state data besides the `WaitHandle`, proper synchronization is required (with [locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) etc).

Comment: If the code is in a STA, `COWAIT_DISPATCH_WINDOW_MESSAGES` is required.  [Chris Brumme's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2004/02/02/66219.aspx) (referenced in your nested message loop article) emphasizes this.  Incoming COM calls arrive via window messages.  Overall, I prefer your solution (I just *knew* someone at MSFT had already packaged up the MsgWaitForMultipleObjects code); it's cleaner & simpler; but the odds are @Rauld will have to pump.

Comment: @EricBrown, a great point, thank you. I did not know `COWAIT_DISPATCH_CALLS` is not enough for STA. The article you mentioned looks a must-read, yet i overlooked it, get to catch-up.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want to pump messages while waiting for an event.  For this, [MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931971.aspx) is invaluable.  I have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966387/c-msapi-5-setnotifycallbackfunction-not-working/18021173#18021173) (to a different question) that demonstrates a common usage pattern for `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`.

Comment: do you have a C# example ?

Comment: @EricBrown, as long as we have to pump messages, using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` might actually be more appropriate than `CoWaitForMultipleHandles`, because the former would allow using `Application.DoEvents` instead of native `PeekMessage/TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage`.

Comment: @Rauld - I don't really have an example, but [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) has signatures for all the native functions.

Comment: @Noseratio - another good point.  (I do all my development in C++, and sometimes it shows. :))