# Await and SynchronizationContext in a managed component hosted by an unmanaged app

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, com-interop

**[EDITED]** *[This appears to be a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19555959/1768303) in the Framework's implementation of [Application.DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx), which I've reported [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806432/application-doevents-resets-the-threads-current-synchronization-context). Restoring a wrong synchronization context on a UI thread may seriously affect component developers like me. The goal of the bounty is to draw more attention to this problem and to reward @MattSmith whose answer helped tracking it down.*

I'm responsible for a .NET WinForms `UserControl`-based component exposed as ActiveX to **a legacy unmanaged app**, via COM interop. The runtime requirement is .NET 4.0 + Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

The component gets instantiated and used on the app's main STA UI thread. Its implementation utilizes `async/await`, so it expects that an instance of a serializing synchronization context has been installed on the current thread (i. e.,`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`).

Usually, `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` gets set up by `Application.Run`, which is where the message loop of a managed app runs. Naturally, **this is not the case for the unmanaged host app**, and I have no control over this. Of course, the host app still has its own classic Windows message loop, so it should not be a problem to serialize `await` continuation callbacks.

However, none of the solutions I've come up with so far is perfect, or even works properly. Here's an artificial example, where `Test` method is invoked by the host app:

```
Task testTask;

public void Test()
{
    this.testTask = TestAsync();
}

async Task TestAsync()
{
    Debug.Print("thread before await: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    var ctx1 = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    Debug.Print("ctx1: {0}", ctx1 != null? ctx1.GetType().Name: null);

    if (!(ctx1 is WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext))
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());

    var ctx2 = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    Debug.Print("ctx2: {0}", ctx2.GetType().Name);

    await TaskEx.Delay(1000);

    Debug.WriteLine("thread after await: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    var ctx3 = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    Debug.Print("ctx3: {0}", ctx3 != null? ctx3.GetType().Name: null);

    Debug.Print("ctx3 == ctx1: {0}, ctx3 == ctx2: {1}", ctx3 == ctx1, ctx3 == ctx2);
}
```

Debug output:

```
thread before await: 1
ctx1: SynchronizationContext
ctx2: WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
thread after await: 1
ctx3: SynchronizationContext
ctx3 == ctx1: True, ctx3 == ctx2: False
```

Although it continues on the same thread, the `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` context I'm installing on the current thread before `await` **gets reset to the default `SynchronizationContext`** after it, for some reason.

**Why does it get reset?** I've verified my component is the only .NET component being used by that app. The app itself does call `CoInitialize/OleInitialize` properly.

I've also tried **setting up `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` in the constructor of a static singleton object**, so it gets installed on the thread when my managed assembly gets loaded. That didn't help: when `Test` is later invoked on the same thread, the context has been already reset to the default one.

I'm considering using a [custom awaiter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx) to schedule `await` callbacks via `control.BeginInvoke` of my control, so the above would look like `await TaskEx.Delay().WithContext(control)`. That should work for my own `awaits`, as long as the host app keeps pumping messages, but not for `awaits` inside any of the 3rd party assemblies my assembly may be referencing.

I'm still researching this. **Any ideas on how to keep the correct thread affinity for `await` in this scenario would be appreciated.**

Comment: Hard to guess at this.  The stranger detail is why SynchronizationContext.Current isn't null when the code starts running.  We can't see how the code got started from the unmanaged program.  You are probably battling a problem with Thread.ExecutionContext, it copies the SynchronizationContext and restores it.

Comment: @HansPassant, could such behavior be a part of the interop layer? I'll try to create a simple repro case.

Comment: Well, sure.  Don't expect this to work when this code got activated from a thread other than the unmanaged program's UI thread.  The one that pumps the message loop and called CoInitializeEx() specifying COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED.

Comment: @HansPassant, yep, both conditions for the unmanaged app have been specifically verified with the author.

Comment: Don't take his word for it, verify it.  Enable unmanaged debugging and set a breakpoint on the code.  Look at the call stack and verify that you see KiUserCallbackDispatch and InternalCallWinProc on the call stack.  And use Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() and check that you get STA back.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is going to be a bit long. First of all, thanks **Matt Smith** and **Hans Passant** for your ideas, they have been very helpful.

The problem was caused by a good old friend, `Application.DoEvents`, although in a novelty way. Hans has [an excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/1768303) about why `DoEvents` is an evil. Unfortunately, I'm unable to avoid using `DoEvents` in this control, because of the synchronous API restrictions posed by the legacy unmanaged host app (more about it at the end). **I'm well aware of the existing implications of `DoEvents`, but here I believe we have a new one:**

*On a thread without explicit WinForms message loop (i.e., any thread which hasn't entered `Application.Run` or `Form.ShowDialog`), calling `Application.DoEvents` will replace the current synchronization context with the default `SynchronizationContext`, provided `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall` is `true` (which is so by default).*

If it is not a bug, then it's a very unpleasant undocumented behavior which may seriously affect some component developers.

Here is a simple console STA app reproducing the problem. **Note how `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` gets (incorrectly) replaced with `SynchronizationContext` in the first pass of `Test` and does not in the second pass.**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThreadAttribute]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Debug.Print("ApartmentState: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState.ToString());
            Debug.Print("*** Test 1 ***");
            Test();
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
            WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall = false;
            Debug.Print("*** Test 2 ***");
            Test();
        }

        static void DumpSyncContext(string id, string message, object ctx)
        {
            Debug.Print("{0}: {1} ({2})", id, ctx != null ? ctx.GetType().Name : "null", message);
        }

        static void Test()
        {
            Debug.Print("WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall: {0}", WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall);
            var ctx1 = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            DumpSyncContext("ctx1", "before setting up the context", ctx1);

            if (!(ctx1 is WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext))
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());

            var ctx2 = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            DumpSyncContext("ctx2", "before Application.DoEvents", ctx2);

            Application.DoEvents();

            var ctx3 = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            DumpSyncContext("ctx3", "after Application.DoEvents", ctx3);

            Debug.Print("ctx3 == ctx1: {0}, ctx3 == ctx2: {1}", ctx3 == ctx1, ctx3 == ctx2);
        }
    }
}
```

**Debug output:**

```
ApartmentState: STA
*** Test 1 ***
WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall: True
ctx1: null (before setting up the context)
ctx2: WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext (before Application.DoEvents)
ctx3: SynchronizationContext (after Application.DoEvents)
ctx3 == ctx1: False, ctx3 == ctx2: False
*** Test 2 ***
WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall: False
ctx1: null (before setting up the context)
ctx2: WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext (before Application.DoEvents)
ctx3: WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext (after Application.DoEvents)
ctx3 == ctx1: False, ctx3 == ctx2: True
```

It took some investigation of the Framework's implementation of `Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner` and `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstalIifNeeded`/`Uninstall` to understand why exactly it happens. The condition is that the thread doesn't currently execute an `Application` message loop, as mentioned above. The relevant piece from `RunMessageLoopInner`:

```
if (this.messageLoopCount == 1)
{
    WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstallIfNeeded();
}
```

Then the code inside `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstallIfNeeded`/`Uninstall` pair of methods **doesn't save/restore the thread's existing synchronization context** correctly. At this point, I'm not sure if it's a bug or a design feature.

**The solution is to disable `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall`**, as simple as this:

```
struct SyncContextSetup
{
    public SyncContextSetup(bool autoInstall)
    {
        WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall = autoInstall;
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());
    }
}

static readonly SyncContextSetup _syncContextSetup =
    new SyncContextSetup(autoInstall: false);
```

**A few words about why I use `Application.DoEvents` in the first place here.** It's a typical asynchronous-to-synchronous bridge code running on the UI thread, using a nested message loop. This is a bad practice, but the legacy host app expects all APIs to complete synchronously. The original problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18050438/1768303). At some later point, I replaced `CoWaitForMultipleHandles` with a combination of `Application.DoEvents`/`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`, which now looks like this:

**[EDITED]** The most recent version of `WaitWithDoEvents` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20876645/1768303). **[/EDITED]**

The idea was to dispatch messages using .NET standard mechanism, rather than relying upon `CoWaitForMultipleHandles` to do so. That's when I implicitly introduced the problem with the synchronization context, due to the described behavior of `DoEvents`.

The legacy app is currently being rewritten using modern technologies, and so is the control. The current implementation is aimed for existing customers with Windows XP who cannot upgrade for reasons beyond our control.

**Finally, here's the implementation of the custom awaiter** which I mentioned in my question as an option to mitigate the problem. It was an interesting experience and it works, but **it cannot be considered a proper solution**.

```
/// <summary>
/// AwaitHelpers - custom awaiters
/// WithContext continues on the control's thread after await
/// E.g.: await TaskEx.Delay(1000).WithContext(this)
/// </summary>
public static class AwaitHelpers
{
    public static ContextAwaiter<T> WithContext<T>(this Task<T> task, Control control, bool alwaysAsync = false)
    {
        return new ContextAwaiter<T>(task, control, alwaysAsync);
    }

    // ContextAwaiter<T>
    public class ContextAwaiter<T> : INotifyCompletion
    {
        readonly Control _control;
        readonly TaskAwaiter<T> _awaiter;
        readonly bool _alwaysAsync;

        public ContextAwaiter(Task<T> task, Control control, bool alwaysAsync)
        {
            _awaiter = task.GetAwaiter();
            _control = control;
            _alwaysAsync = alwaysAsync;
        }

        public ContextAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter() { return this; }

        public bool IsCompleted { get { return !_alwaysAsync && _awaiter.IsCompleted; } }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            if (_alwaysAsync || _control.InvokeRequired)
            {
                Action<Action> callback = (c) => _awaiter.OnCompleted(c);
                _control.BeginInvoke(callback, continuation);
            }
            else
                _awaiter.OnCompleted(continuation);
        }

        public T GetResult()
        {
            return _awaiter.GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you suspect that this is a bug, then I think you should [report it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

Comment: @svick, I already did: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806432/application-doevents-resets-the-threads-current-synchronization-context

Comment: @noseratio, excellent post and fix. Thank you a lot! Do you know status of this bug? MS Connection doesn't work more.

Comment: @23W glad it helped. I believe they decided to leave it as is for "compatibility reasons". You could investigate their current implementation [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs,11ce7ff2c55ebd9d).

Comment: Where should I put the line "static readonly SyncContextSetup"? I manully new the "SyncContextSetup" struct in the main form constructor which has no effect.

Comment: @Tomingsun, as far as remember, in your `Main` function, before everything else. Look for `[STAThread]`, your `Main` should have it.

Answer (score 7):

The WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext gets installed automatically when a control is created unless you've turned that off.  So, unless someone else stomps over it after your control is created, there is nothing special to do.

You could set a breakpoint on WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstalIifNeeded to see when that happens.

See:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.autoinstall.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx

(I realize this doesn't answer your question, but didn't want to put this in a comment)

Comment: This looks useful if it applies to CCW controls. I don't know why it was down-voted.

Comment: @Noseratio It's not an answer.  It's a comment posted as an answer, as the answer itself even states.  It also doesn't seem to apply to the OP's case in the least.  That the controls will create their own context wouldn't change the fact that, in this case, the context is constantly being reset to an incorrect context.  The OP's code is just a simpler way of replicating the problem.

Comment: @MattSmith, the solution to the problem turned to be quite opposite: set `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall` to `false` (it was `true` by default) and install the context manually (I'll post more details on why). So, while your answer technically is not the answer, it happened to be extremely helpful to get me on the right path. I wish I could vote it up twice, but I can't. I will however reward your answer with a gratuity bounty when it becomes available tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: @Noseratio, interesting.  Thanks for keeping me posted.

Comment: @Noseratio, thanks for the bounty, glad it helped to lead you in the tight direction.