# How to wait for signal in WinForms while also listening to events?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, events, handler

**Case 1**

Here is my setup.

```
internal class MyClass
{
    private ApiObject apiObject;

    private bool cond1;
    private bool cond2;

    internal MyClass()
    {
        this.apiObject = new ApiObject();
        this.apiObject.ApiStateUpdate += new ApiStateUpdateEventHandler(ApiStateHandler);

        //wait for both conditions to be true
    }

    private void ApiStateHandler(string who, int howMuch)
    {
        if(who.Equals("Something") && howMuch == 1)
            this.cond1 = true;
        else if(who.Equals("SomethingElse") && howMuch == 1)
            this.cond2 = true;
    }
}
```

How can I *wait for both conditions to be true*?

If I do:

```
while(!(this.cond1 && this.cond2))
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

the code in the `ApiStateHandler()` never seems to execute.

If I do:

```
while(!(this.cond1 && this.cond2))
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
}
```

this works but seems like a waste of resources and a hack.

Basically I think I need a way to `wait` but without blocking the Thread. What's the proper of way of doing this?

**Case 2**

The second case is somewhat similar (and related) and illustrates the same problem.

```
internal class MyClass
{
    private ApiNotifyClass apiNotifyClass;
    private shouldContinue = false;

    internal MyClass()
    {
        //in addition to the code from above
        this.apiNotifyClass = new ApiNotifyClass();
        this.apiNotifyClass.ApiFound += ApiNofityFoundEventHandler(ApiNotifyHandler);
    }

    internal void Send(SomethingToSend somethigToSend)
    {
        Verifyer verifier = this.apiObject.ApiGet(somethingToSend);
        this.apiNotifyClass.ApiAttach(verifier);

        //wait for the shouldContinue to be true

        this.apiObject.ApiSend(verifier);

        this.apiNotifyClass.ApiDetach(verifier);
    }

    private void ApiNotifyHandler()
    {
        this.shouldContinue = true;
    }
}
```

When calling `Send()`, the `Verifier` object will be created and the method needs to wait for the `ApiNotifyHandler` to execute (i.e., the `ApiFound` event to occur) before calling the `ApiSend()`.

So this is the same situation as is in **Case 1**. How should I *wait for the shouldContinue to be true*?

Sorry for the very long question, but I thought of giving as much information as possible to help you help me.

[**Update**]

I'm forced to use .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to deal with this is to re-factor your code to use `async/await` and turn `ApiStateUpdate` event into an awaitable task with `TaskCompletionSource` ([EAP pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622454.aspx)).

If your really want to wait synchronously for an event on a UI thread, look at `WaitWithDoEvents` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19555959/1768303) or `CoWaitForMultipleHandles` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18050438/1768303), they do just that. Keep in mind, this approach creates a nested modal message loop, with possible code re-entrancy being the most notable implication (discussed in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/1768303)).

**[EDITED]** What you're trying to do here is an asynchronous-to-synchronous bridge, which is almost always a bad idea on its own. Moreover, I just realized you're doing this in a constructor. Constructors, by their nature, should not have any asynchronous code inside, they're atomic. There is always a better way to factor a lengthy initialization procedure out of the constructor. @StephenCleary talks about this in his very informative [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Regarding .NET 2.0 restrictions. While `async/await` might be a revolutionary concept, the state machine concept behind it is nothing new. You can always simulate it with a chain of delegate callbacks and events. Anonymous delegates has been there since .NET 2.0. For example, your code might look like this:

```
internal class MyClass
{
    private ApiObject apiObject;

    public event EventHandler Initialized;

    internal MyClass()
    {
        this.apiObject = new ApiObject();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        ApiStateUpdateEventHandler handler = null;

        handler = delegate(string who, int howMuch) 
        {
            bool cond1 = false;
            bool cond2 = false;

            if(who.Equals("Something") && howMuch == 1)
                cond1 = true;
            else if(who.Equals("SomethingElse") && howMuch == 1)
                cond2 = true;           

            //wait for both conditions to be true

            if ( !cond1 && !cond2 )
                return;

            this.apiObject.ApiStateUpdate -= handler;

            // fire an event when both conditions are met
            if (this.Initialized != null)
                this.Initialized(this, new EventArgs());
        };

        this.apiObject.ApiStateUpdate += handler;
    }
}
```

The client code using `MyClass` might look like this:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.Initialized += delegate 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello!"); 
};
myObject.Initialize();
```

**The above would be the proper asynchronous event-based pattern for .NET 2.0**. An easier, but worse solution would be to implement the asynchronous-to-synchronous bridge, using `WaitWithDoEvents` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19555959/1768303), based on `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`), which may look like this:

```
internal class MyClass
{
    private ApiObject apiObject;

    internal MyClass()
    {
        this.apiObject = new ApiObject();
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        using (ManualResetEvent syncEvent = new ManualResetEvent())
        {
            ApiStateUpdateEventHandler handler = null;

            handler = delegate(string who, int howMuch) 
            {
                bool cond1 = false;
                bool cond2 = false;

                if(who.Equals("Something") && howMuch == 1)
                cond1 = true;
                else if(who.Equals("SomethingElse") && howMuch == 1)
                    cond2 = true;           

                //wait for both conditions to be true

                if ( !cond1 && !cond2 )
                    return;

                this.apiObject.ApiStateUpdate -= handler;

                syncEvent.Set();
            };

            this.apiObject.ApiStateUpdate += handler;
            WaitWithDoEvents(syncEvent, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
}
```

Yet that'd be still more efficient than a busy waiting loop from your question:

```
while(!(this.cond1 && this.cond2))
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Two things: `myObject.Initialized = delegate` should use `+=` instead of `=` and `var` is not available in .Net 2.0 (maybe you can make these two changes so I can accept the answer). I've tested the first solution and it works OK.

Comment: @Yeseanul, indeed, I was typing right out of my head. The code updated as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to execute the blocking code asynchronously. Otherwise you would hang up the UI thread which is not good. There are various different ways to do this. Here is one that uses the new `async` and `await` keywords. I admit right up front that this is a lot to swallow and is only feasible in .NET 4.5+.

**Regarding Case #1**

First, convert your EAP (event-based asynchronous patter) into a TAP (task-based asynchronous pattern). This looks ugly because EAP is hard to deal with. You have to subscribe to the event and then unsubscribe when you are done with it.

```
private Task<ApiObject> CreateApiObjectAsync()
{
  bool cond1 = false;
  bool cond2 = false;

  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ApiObject>();

  ApiObject instance = null;
  ApiStateEventHandler handler = null;

  handler = (who, howmuch) =>
    {
      cond1 = cond1 || (who == "Something" && howmuch == 1);
      cond2 = cond2 || (who == "SomethingElse" && howmuch == 1);
      if (cond1 && cond2)
      {
        instance.ApiStateUpdate -= handler;
        tcs.SetResult(instance);
      }
    }

  var instance = new ApiObject();
  instance.ApiStateUpdate += handler;
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Once you have that in place then it would be used like this.

```
internal class MyClass
{
    private ApiObject apiObject;

    internal MyClass()
    {
      InitializeAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
      apiObject = await CreateApiObjectAsync();
      // At this point the instance is created and fully initialized.
    }
}
```

I recommend that you read [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)'s blog on [asynchronous initialization](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) using `async` and `await` before you do this though. Actually, read through all of his Async OOP series. It is really good.

**Regarding Case #2**

In a lot of ways this case is easier to deal with because constructors and object initialization do not come into play. You will still need to use the same strategy as above though. First, convert the API's EAP style into the TAP style. If this wait condition is not dependent on an event from `ApiObject` then just right whatever wait logic you need in the TAP method and periodically evaluate it. Preferably this would be done without doiing a busy wait. Then `await` the TAP method you created. Do not forget to mark `Send` as `async` when doing this though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Very thorough, but I am forced to use .Net 2.0 (I've also edited the question to reflect this).

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I think I need a way to wait but without blocking the
>   Thread.

You do want to block the thread, just not the UI thread.  Therefore simply create another thread and block that.  Make it easy and use the BackgroundWorker() control.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123661/how-to-wait-for-a-backgroundworker-to-cancel) are some interesting resources. But I couldn't figure out a way of using a `BackgroudWorker` to solve the issue. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: No...I think I misread the question.  I don't see any clean way to do it.