# How to write an "awaitable" method?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm finally looking into the async & await keywords, which I kind of "get", but all the examples I've seen call async methods in the .Net framework, e.g. [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async), which calls `HttpClient.GetStringAsync()`.

What I'm not so clear on is what goes on in such a method, and how I would write my own "awaitable" method. Is it as simple as wrapping the code that I want to run asynchronously in a Task and returning that?

Comment: Or writing an async method that returns a `Task` or `Task<T>`, of course. Async is nicely composable in that way.

Comment: I am just learning C#.  I was looking at the same example with GetStringAsync(), and I had the exact same question as the OP, despite being a veteran Java multi-threader.  It's a great question and should probably be addressed in the MSDN article which is otherwise very complete.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
Task.Run(() => ExpensiveTask());
```

To make it an awaitable method:

```
public Task ExpensiveTaskAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => ExpensiveTask());
}
```

The important thing here is to return a task. The method doesn't even have to be marked async. (Just read a little bit further for it to come into the picture)

Now this can be called as

```
async public void DoStuff()
{
    PrepareExpensiveTask();
    await ExpensiveTaskAsync();
    UseResultsOfExpensiveTask();
}
```

Note that here the method signature says `async`, since the method may return control to the caller until `ExpensiveTaskAsync()` returns. Also, expensive in this case means time-consuming, like a web request or similar. To send off heavy computation to another thread, it is usually better to use the "old" approaches, i.e. `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` for GUI applications or `System.Threading.Thread`.

Comment: It is correct that the most natural and usual way to make an awaitable method is to write a method that returns `Task` or `Task<>`. But technically you can also write a method that returns `YourOwnType` provided that `YourOwnType` has a public parameterless non-static instance method called `GetAwaiter()` whose return type is appropriate (find details elsewhere). So `await` is a bit like `foreach`, it works on any type that has a suitable public method.

Comment: That's good to know! Although it probably won't help the readability of your code if you decide to use this approach.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen `foreach` requires `IEnumerable`. I'm a little disappointed that `await` uses duck typing when an interface would be more appropriate for the language. The fact that it is 'for compiler use' is a poor excuse.

Comment: @Gusdor Why, `foreach` does not require any interfaces! Just try these classes: `class ForeachMe
    {
        public StrangeType GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new StrangeType();
        }
    }
    class StrangeType
    {
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return true;
        }
        public DateTime Current
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }` With them, the code `foreach (var x in new ForeachMe())
                { Console.WriteLine(x); }` will work just fine.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I wouldn't bet on this being immune to breaking changes. Is that in the language spec? See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Comment: @Gusdor The definitive source is the section [The foreach statement (old version)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754.aspx) in the official C# Language Specification. Find the same section in the [newest version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx). This is well specified; the type need not implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: In general, a great answer - but you should not use BackgroundWorker in new code anymore. Use Task.Run() instead - even for heavy computation. More at: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html

Comment: I know it is an old post. But I have a question: If async and await does NOT create any additional thread, where are the long running processes run then? I mean there gotta be someone doing the work somewhere. So who runs them? My current explanation is they are being run in a complete different PROCESS by the OS. But I know it is not that correct. Otherwise I would've found same reference in MSDN.Can anyone help clarify this?

Comment: `Task.Async()`  to my knowlegde actually sends the task  to a threadpool. Most OS functions which are marked `async` are I/O-Operations, so they do not need a new thread to run on- they just need to wait for the OS's interrupt.

Answer (score 18):

> ... how I would write my own "awaitable" method.

Returning a `Task` is not the only way. You have an option to create a *custom awaiter* (by implementing `GetAwaiter` and [`INotifyCompletion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.inotifycompletion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), here is a great read: ["Await anything"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-anything/). Examples of .NET APIs returning custom awaiters: `Task.Yield()`, `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`.

I have some posts with custom awaiters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18779393/1768303) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19555959/1768303), e.g:

```
// don't use this in production
public static class SwitchContext
{
    public static Awaiter Yield() { return new Awaiter(); }

    public struct Awaiter : System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion
    {
        public Awaiter GetAwaiter() { return this; }

        public bool IsCompleted { get { return false; } }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => ((Action)state)(), continuation);
        }

        public void GetResult() { }
    }
}

// ...

await SwitchContext.Yield();
```

Comment: `// don't use this in production`
— why exactly?

Comment: @hypersw, [here is why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363413/why-was-switchto-removed-from-async-ctp-release).

Comment: can't take that for a good “why” but for one specific detail which I've traced down the links, about `await`s not available in `finally`s and the consequences, which anyway does not hold any more. The rest is all very speculative, like bad-looking code (`Task::StartNew` each section rather than `await YieldTo`? only if you haven't tried for yourself), or being semantically unclear (as opposed to `ConfigureAwait(false)`, I assume?).

Comment: I guess it all comes down to scenarios. If you got a dozen context switches in one function, it helps. If you only start big background tasks, you'd be safer without.

Comment: The "Await anything" link is dead. I assume this is the new link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-anything/

Answer (score 17):

> How I would write my own "awaitable" method? Is it as simple as wrapping the code that I want to run asynchronously in a `Task` and returning that?

That is one option, but it's most likely not what you want to do, because it doesn't actually give you many of the advantages of asynchronous code. For more details, see [Stephen Toub's *Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

In general, methods are not awaitable, *types* are. If you want to be able to write something like `await MyMethod()`, then `MyMethod()` has to return `Task`, `Task<T>` or a custom `await`able type. Using a custom type is a rare and advanced scenario; using `Task`, you have several options:

- Write your method using `async` and `await`. This is useful for *composing* actions asynchronously, but it can't be used for the inner-most `await`able calls.
- Create the `Task` using one of the methods on `Task`, like `Task.Run()` or `Task.FromAsync()`.
- Use [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174). This is the most general approach, it can be used to create `await`able methods from anything that will happen in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, technically you only need to return a `Task` or `Task<Result>` from an `async` method to implement an awaitable method.

This supports the [*Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

There are several ways of implementing the TAP, however. See [*Implementing the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873177%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

(But all these implementations still return `Task` or `Task<Result>`, of course.)

Answer (score 5):

Just convert your method to Task. Like @Romiox I usually use this extention:

```
public static partial class Ext
{
    #region Public Methods
    public static Task ToTask(Action action)
    {
        return Task.Run(action);
    }
    public static Task<T> ToTask<T>(Func<T> function)
    {
        return Task.Run(function);
    }
    public static async Task ToTaskAsync(Action action)
    {
        return await Task.Run(action);
    }
    public static async Task<T> ToTaskAsync<T>(Func<T> function)
    {
        return await Task.Run(function);
    }
    #endregion Public Methods
}
```

Now let we say you have

```
void foo1()...

void foo2(int i1)...

int foo3()...

int foo4(int i1)...
```

...

Then you can declare your[async Method] like @Romiox

```
async Task foo1Async()
{
    return await Ext.ToTask(() => foo1());
}
async Task foo2Async(int i1)
{
    return await Ext.ToTask(() => foo2(i1));
}
async Task<int> foo3Async()
{
    return await Ext.ToTask(() => foo3());
}
async Task<int> foo4Async(int i1)
{
    return await Ext.ToTask(() => foo4(i1));
}
```

OR

```
async Task foo1Async()
{
    return await Ext.ToTaskAsync(() => foo1());
}
async Task foo2Async(int i1)
{
    return await Ext.ToTaskAsync(() => foo2(i1));
}
async Task<int> foo3Async()
{
    return await Ext.ToTaskAsync(() => foo3());
}
async Task<int> foo4Async(int i1)
{
    return await Ext.ToTaskAsync(() => foo4(i1));
}
```

...

Now you can use async and await for any of the fooAsync methods e.g. foo4Async

```
async Task<int> TestAsync () {
    ///Initial Code
    int m = 3;
    ///Call the task
    var X = foo4Async(m);
    ///Between
    ///Do something while waiting comes here
    ///..
    var Result = await X;
    ///Final
    ///Some Code here
    return Result;
}
```

Comment: Where is the await keyword in your example?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a `Task`, you may write a completely customized awaitable object. Such object is one implementing a method `GetAwaiter ()` returning an object implementing `INotifyCompletion`, which can be the object itself.

More: [INotifyCompletion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.inotifycompletion?view=netframework-4.8)

The awaiter implements:

- `IsCompleted` is get the state
- `GetResult ()` to get the result
- `OnCompleted (Action continuation)` to set the continuation delegate.

The awaitable object contains some method for actual payload (e.g. below, the method is `Run`).

```
class Program {
    // Need to change the declaration of Main() in order to use 'await'
    static async Task Main () {
        // Create a custom awaitable object
        MyAwaitable awaitable = new MyAwaitable ();

        // Run awaitable payload, ignore returned Task
        _ = awaitable.Run ();

        // Do some other tasks while awaitable is running
        Console.WriteLine ("Waiting for completion...");

        // Wait for completion
        await awaitable;

        Console.WriteLine ("The long operation is now complete. " + awaitable.GetResult());
    }
}

public class MyAwaitable : INotifyCompletion {
    // Fields
    private Action continuation = null;
    private string result = string.Empty;

    // Make this class awaitable
    public MyAwaitable GetAwaiter () { return this; }

    // Implementation of INotifyCompletion for the self-awaiter
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
    public string GetResult () { return result; }
    public void OnCompleted (Action continuation) {
        // Store continuation delegate
        this.continuation = continuation;
        Console.WriteLine ("Continuation set");
    }

    // Payload to run
    public async Task Run () {
        Console.WriteLine ("Computing result...");

        // Wait 2 seconds
        await Task.Delay (2000);
        result = "The result is 10";

        // Set completed
        IsCompleted = true;

        Console.WriteLine ("Result available");

        // Continue with the continuation provided
        continuation?.Invoke ();
    }
}
```