# C# async tasks: do all participating methods have to be async as well?

Tags: c#, async-await

When we are dealing with async tasks, the task consists of multiple method calls (possibly of other classes) which in turn consist of yet further method calls. We could call this a tree. Do all methods have to be of type async task for the original task to truly behave async?
Would the answer be true for any kind of background task of other similar languages, mostly Java as well?
(In C#, once I had one of my methods somewhere in this tree get into an infinite loop (talk about a long running task!), yet sadly, the original async task's isRunning property returned false.)

Comment: you should provide us with a snippet of the code you have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do all methods have to be of type async task for the original task to truly behave async?

In order to behave asynchronously, an `async` method must have an `await` statement for an operation that is not already completed.

I think my [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) would be helpful for you.

> Would the answer be true for any kind of background task of other similar languages, mostly Java as well?

Yes.

> sadly, the original async task's isRunning property returned false

I assume you mean that the `TaskStatus` was not `TaskStatus.Running`. [This is normal and expected](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html), since asynchronous tasks are [Promise Tasks, not Delegate Tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html) (see my blog for more info).

Comment: Maybe my awaitable method stopped running because it was started in a new thread? `analysisthread = new Thread(async () => await a.analyze(afile, someID, arg3));`

Comment: Starting a new thread for asynchronous work is highly unusual (the `async` code is most likely resuming on a thread pool thread, not the custom thread). If you want to run asynchronous work on a thread pool context, use `Task.Run` instead of `Thread`.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. Async means that work being done by another process can be handed off to that process and so not block the calling thread. All the better if those processes don’t reside on the same machine, since that work will occupy very little compute or IO at the caller. This is achieved by suspending method execution using the async/await mechanism, which promises to resume on some synchronisation context once completed. So, why the overview?

Because this means that we can and should judiciously choose those operations that should be async, and so apply the await keyword in an async method. Some won’t need it, since they are lightweight and adding async to them may even add compute time to them, due to the creation of the async state machine. So the operations in a method can often be a mixture of asynchronous and synchronous code.

And this in turn means that some methods would use the Task return type with async/await, and some will be regular, synchronous methods.

Answer (score 1):

No, they don't have to. Simple example, in a Forms application this

```
button.Click += async (_, __) =>
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => MyClass.SomeTimeconsumingMethod());
                };
```

still lets you move the window during the execution of `SomeTimeconsumingMethod`, whereas this one

```
button.Click += (_, __) =>
                {
                    MyClass.SomeTimeconsumingMethod();
                };
```

doesn't let you do it.

Answer (score 0):

The only requirement for using the `await` keyword is that the method you are awaiting returns a `Task` or `Task<T>`.

The exact implementation of this method (`async` or `return someTask`) has no influence on the correctness of the code, although it may influence the function.

Any *normal* code can run in an `async` method alongside your `await` calls. The only significant restriction is that `out` and `ref` are not allowed.

Comment: So you mean all the other methods in the method can be of any type?

Comment: Technically, you need a method which returns an `awaitable` result. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21702041/6469077

Comment: @heinzbeinz When explaining async / await to learners I try to leave out that particular duck typed horrorshow. It is unnecessary detail.

Comment: @Gusdor And you are totally right that way. I just wanted to add the awaitable as a reference.

Comment: @heinzbeinz Thanks for that too, though, it's interesting to know I have even more freedom with tasks.

Answer (score 0):

> Do all methods have to be of type async task for the original task to truly behave async

It depends on what do you mean by "*all*" word.

Some APIs must not be asynchronous. Think about `List<T>.Add`, for example. Do you really want it to be asynchronous?
Some APIs should be asynchronous, but there's no asynchronous counterpart (e.g. [SMO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms162169.aspx), or [`File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) static class).

*Ideally* you should do "async all the way", when talking about IO-bound operations. But IRL you can face with violation of this rule, when some part of your `async` method chain will execute IO-bound operation synchronously.

Comment: I think the question is asking whether the combination of `async` and `Task` is the mechanism to enable async execution, not whether all code should be async

Comment: @DvS I mean do all methods in the call chain have to be async, or only the 'first' one.