# Difference between using Task.Yield() in a User Interface and Console App

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await, console

I'm trying to asynchronously show a progress form that says the application is running while the actual application is running.

As following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406939/async-showdialog), I have the following:

**Main Form:**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async Task<int> LoadDataAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        return 42;
    }

    private async void Run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var runningForm = new RunningForm();

        runningForm.ShowRunning();

        var progressFormTask = runningForm.ShowDialogAsync();

        var data = await LoadDataAsync();

        runningForm.Close();
        await progressFormTask;

        MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Progress Form**

```
public partial class RunningForm : Form
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext;

    public RunningForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    public async void ShowRunning()
    {
        this.RunningLabel.Text = "Running";
        int dots = 0;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                UpadateUi($"Running{new string('.', dots)}");

                Thread.Sleep(300);

                dots = (dots == 3) ? 0 : dots + 1;
            }
        });
    }

    public void UpadateUi(string text)
    {
        synchronizationContext.Post(
            new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
            {
                this.RunningLabel.Text = text;
            }),
            text);
    }

    public void CloseThread()
    {
        synchronizationContext.Post(
            new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
            {
                this.Close();
            }),
            null);
    }
}

internal static class DialogExt
{
    public static async Task<DialogResult> ShowDialogAsync(this Form form)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        if (form.IsDisposed)
        {
            return DialogResult.OK;
        }
        return form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

The above works fine, but it doesn't work when I'm calling from outside of another from. This is my console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Test().Run();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Test
{
    private RunningForm runningForm;

    public async void Run()
    {
        var runningForm = new RunningForm();

        runningForm.ShowRunning();

        var progressFormTask = runningForm.ShowDialogAsync();

        var data = await LoadDataAsync();

        runningForm.CloseThread();

        await progressFormTask;

        MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());
    }

    async Task<int> LoadDataAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Watching what happens with the debugger, the process gets to `await Task.Yield()` and never progresses to `return form.ShowDialog()` and thus you never see the `RunningForm`. The process then goes to `LoadDataAsync()` and hangs forever on `await Task.Delay(2000)`.

Why is this happening? Does it have something to do with how `Task`s are prioritized (ie: [`Task.Yield()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield?view=netframework-4.7.2))?

Comment: I believe your tasks are not hanging by themselves, but that your problems are rather caused by trying to establish a WinForms-based UI in a console application without setting up a message pump (that is required for the WinForms UI to work). Try to instantiate and run your main form in a similar fashion as to what is shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/277776/2819245. Try it and see whether it improves (or otherwise changes) the behavior.

Comment: Also, since you work with tasks (and thus possibly with multiple threads), pay attention to that you create the message pump (i.e., execute `Application.Run`) in the main thread of your program and not in some background thread.

Comment: The code you linked (which I'm the author of) is meant to be run from a WinForms UI thread with a message loop, as @elgonzo pointed out. You said *" "but it doesn't work when I'm calling from outside of another from. This is my console app..."* So, do you ultimately need to run it from another form, or from a non-UI worker thread?

Comment: @noseratio I don't need it to, I'm more interested in learning why it works for WinForms and not for Console Applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Watching what happens with the debugger, the process gets to await
>   Task.Yield() and never progresses to return form.ShowDialog() and thus
>   you never see the RunningForm. The process then goes to
>   LoadDataAsync() and hangs forever on await Task.Delay(2000).
>
> Why is this happening?

What happens here is that when you do `var runningForm = new RunningForm()` on a console thread without any synchronization context (`System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` is null), it implicitly creates an instance of `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` and installs it on the current thread, more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19535147/1768303).

Then, when you hit `await Task.Yield()`, the `ShowDialogAsync` method returns to the caller and the `await` continuation is posted to that new synchronization context. However, the continuation never gets a chance to be invoked, because the current thread doesn't run a message loop and the posted messages don't get pumped. There isn't a deadlock, but the code after `await Task.Yield()` is never executed, so the dialog doesn't even get shown. The same is true about `await Task.Delay(2000)`.

> I'm more interested in learning why it works for WinForms and not for
>   Console Applications.

You need a UI thread with a message loop in your console app. Try refactoring your console app like this:

```
public void Run()
{
    var runningForm = new RunningForm();
    runningForm.Loaded += async delegate 
    {
        runningForm.ShowRunning();

        var progressFormTask = runningForm.ShowDialogAsync();

        var data = await LoadDataAsync();

        runningForm.Close();

        await progressFormTask;

        MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());
    };
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(runningForm);
}
```

Here, the job of `Application.Run` is to start a modal message loop (and install `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` on the current thread) then show the form. The `runningForm.Loaded` async event handler is invoked on that synchronization context, so the logic inside it should work just as expected.

That however makes `Test.Run` **a synchronous method**, i. e., it only returns when the form is closed and the message loop has ended. If this is not what you want, you'd have to create a separate thread to run your message loop, something like I do [with `MessageLoopApartment` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303).

That said, in a typical WinForms or WPF application you should almost never need a secondary UI thread.